# c++ quick read & write from standard input

Tags: c++, c, performance

How I can improve speeds of read & write the data from standard input (terminal) in c/c++ code?

I use:

```
ios::sync_with_stdio_false();
```

Does any way exist to do that quicker?

Comment: How are you actually reading the data?

Comment: It's difficult to suggest improvements without knowing what you are currently doing.

Comment: Also the type of data is char[] & string.

Comment: Is the bottleneck really the I/O component, or is it actually the data parsing component?

Comment: bottleneck is just input & output. I just want do that faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain `std::streambuf` references from [`std::cin.rdbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) and `std::cout.rdbuf()`. (Yes, it's still called `rdbuf` even when used for output.) Most of the slowdown in iostream occurs in the formatting functionality.

You will have to parse the bytes yourself.

As with anything performance-related, don't believe, assume, or suppose anything that doesn't come directly from profiling a run on a realistic dataset.

By the way, all bets are off if `cin` or `cout` are connected to any kind of terminal. The resulting graphical operations and I/O from `cout` will bring the machine to its knees before your program gets a chance to run, and for `cin` you would have to be a pretty fast typist.